# PHP if variable is empty don't show anything and don't display errors

Tags: php, if-statement, simple-html-dom, is-empty

I am using `simple_html_dom` to grab links from a url but I can't solve this problem i am having.

```
    <?php

        $title_name_lower = strtolower($title_name);

        $file_headers = @get_headers($title_name_lower);

            if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
                 echo '<center><strong style="color: #dd3333;">No links found :( </strong><center>';
            }

            else {

                $title_url = file_get_html(''.$title_name_lower.'');

                $items = array();
                $items_text = array();
                foreach($title_url->find('table[class=alternate_color variousfont] tr td a') as $item)  {
                 $items[] = $item->href.'<br>';
                 $items_text[] = $item->plaintext.'<br>';
                }

                //print_r($items_text);
                //print_r($items);

                $m_title_1 = file_get_html(''.$items[3].'');
                $m_title_2 = file_get_html(''.$items[6].'');
                $m_title_3 = file_get_html(''.$items[9].'');
                $m_title_4 = file_get_html(''.$items[12].'');
                $m_title_5 = file_get_html(''.$items[15].'');
                $m_title_6 = file_get_html(''.$items[27].'');
                $m_title_7 = file_get_html(''.$items[30].'');

                $link_1 = $m_title_1->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links] a', 0)->href;
                $link_2 = $m_title_2->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links] a', 0)->href;
                $link_3 = $m_title_3->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links] a', 0)->href;
                $link_4 = $m_title_4->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links] a', 0)->href;
                $link_5 = $m_title_5->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links] a', 0)->href;
                $link_6 = $m_title_6->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links] a', 0)->href;
                $link_7 = $m_title_7->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links] a', 0)->href;
            }

        echo $link_1.' - '.$items_text[3];
        echo $link_5.' - '.$items_text[15];
        echo $link_7.' - '.$items_text[30];     
    ?>
```

The `$items` variable can be 100 links can be only 4 and if `$items` is for example 50 links the `$items_text` is same (50).

Now when I echo `$link_1`, `$link_5`, `$link_7`, in some pages it works but in some it shows an error:

> **Call to a member function** find() on a non-object

I don't want to show any error. I want if the variable is empty than don't show anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this i think.

```
if (is_object($m_title_7)) {
    $link_7 = $m_title_7->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links] a', 0)->href;
} else {
    $link_7 = "";
}
```

This will check to see if $m_title_7 is an object first and if it is then it will set $link_7.

edit added else to empty $link_7